# Vector potential of long wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Suppose I have a long cylindrical wire of radius $a$ and uniform volume current **J**. How would I find the vector potential outside the wire? I know I can use **A** = $\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int\frac{J}{r}d\tau$, where $r$ is the distance to some point, but I'm a bit confused as to how to set up $r$ and the integration bounds when no actual length is given.

Comment: hint : the setup has cylindrical symmetry and if $\mathbf{J}=J \mathbf{z}^0$ then necessarily $\mathbf{A}=A \mathbf{z}^0$ and $A=A(r)$ may only depend on $r$.

Comment: So would this be correct: Since A = A(r), and $B = \nabla \times A$, then $\frac{\partial A}{\partial r} = \frac{\mu_0J}{2\pi r}$, so $A = \frac{\mu_0 J}{2\pi}\ln(r)$?

Comment: not right, instead use the integral form as in your question. You have two regions: (1) within the cylindrical conductor in whose cross-section the $\mathbf{J}$ is assumed to be uniform (2) outside the wire. Now integrate.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about. How do I set up the integral when no actual length is given?

Comment: if you know what it means then this is all you need to know $\mathbf{A}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\mathbf{J}}{r}d\tau$